# Black screen on flutter engine initialization in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, flutter, carplay

I have a Flutter app that I want to use Carplay with. There was an issue with opening the app from Carplay and it required moving FlutterEngine initialization to AppDelegate. Now it's working fine, but I get a black screen between the splashscreen and first app view. I guess this is due to delayed engine creation. How could I solve that? Here's code from my AppDelegate

```
let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "SharedEngine", project: nil, allowHeadlessExecution: true)

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, GCKLoggerDelegate{
    
    let kReceiverAppID = kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID
    let kDebugLoggingEnabled = true
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    flutterEngine.run()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: flutterEngine)
      
    let criteria = GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: kReceiverAppID)
    let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: criteria)
    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
    GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().useDefaultExpandedMediaControls = true
    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self
      
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you give `LaunchScreen` to the `Launch screen interface file base name`
don't give `LaunchScreen.xstoryboard`

Comment: If you're using Firebase then make sure it is initialized correctly!